# What is the Azure WebJobs SDK 3.0 version of host.Call()

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

In WebJobs 2.0 I had a `[NoAutomaticTriggers]` function (called `Start`) that I would execute manually in the startup of my Azure WebJob, like so:

```
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.Call(typeof(AccountingSystemSyncerFunctions).GetMethod("Start"));
host.RunAndBlock();
```

How do I do this in WebJobs SDK 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

Found it here under `Manual Triggers`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#triggers